# Can't use getFont in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have to use minimum requirement for uset getFont in Android studio, this is my gradle

[image: My Gradle Informatiaon]

This is the error notification when I use getFont

[image: My Error Notification]

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get that error is that minSdkVersion defines the minimum version your app is eligible to run.

> **minSdkVersion**: An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.

You can use this method from the support framework to get the font for all older versions:

```
ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, font_id)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat

Comment: but when I use it in another computer, it's work. with same android version and gradle